# join two dataframes on common column

Tags: sql, pandas, join, dataframe

I want to join two data sources, orders and customers:

orders is an SQL Server table:

```
orderid| customerid | orderdate | ordercost
------ | -----------| --------- | --------
12000  | 1500       |2008-08-09 |  38610
```

and customers is a csv file:

```
customerid,first_name,last_name,starting_date,ending_date,country
1500,Sian,Read,2008-01-07,2010-01-07,Greenland
```

I want to join these two tables in my Python application, so I wrote the following code:

```
# Connect to SQL Sever with Pyodbc library

connection = pypyodbc.connect("connection string here")
cursor=connection.cursor();
cursor.execute("SELECT * from order)
result= cursor.fetchall()

# convert the result to pandas Dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(result, columns= ['orderid','customerid','orderdate','ordercost'])

# Read CSV File
df2=pd.read_csv(customer_csv)

# Merge two dataframes
merged= pd.merge( df1, df2, on= 'customerid', how='inner')
print(merged[['first_name', 'country']])
```

I expect

```
first_name | country
-----------|--------
Sian       | Greenland
```

But I get empty result.

When I perform this code for two data frames that are both from CSV files, it works fine. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is columns `customerid` has different `dtypes` in both `DataFrames` so no match.

So need convert both columns to `int` or both to `str`.

```
df1['customerid'] = df1['customerid'].astype(int)
df2['customerid'] = df2['customerid'].astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df1['customerid'] = df1['customerid'].astype(str)
df2['customerid'] = df2['customerid'].astype(str)
```

Also is possible omit `how='inner'`, because default value of [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
merged= pd.merge( df1, df2, on= 'customerid')
```

Comment: Yes the problem was that the type of 'customerid' was object , so I converted it to int and it works now, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for accepting, already your question  was upvoted. Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

empty dataframe result for pd.merge means you don't have any matching values across the two frames. Have you checked the type of the the data? use

```
df1['customerid'].dtype
```

to check.

as well as converting after importing (as suggested in the other answer), you can also tell pandas what dtype you want when you read the csv

```
df2=pd.read_csv(customer_csv, dtype={'customerid': str))
```