# Merge two data frames in Python on column with non-unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes in Python based on column 'X'.

The column X in left dataframe has non-unique values and the column X in right dataframe has unique values. How can I merge the values from the right dataframe into the left dataframe?

I want to merge rows from df2 into df1 to form df3

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['NA','EU','LA','ME'],
                    'B': [50, 23,21,100],
                    'X': ['IW233', 'IW455', 'IW455', 'IW100']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [50, 12, 12, 11, 10, 16],
                    'X': ['IW455', 'IW200', 'IW233', 'IW150', 'IW175', 'IW100'],
                    'D': ['Aug', 'Sep', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec', 'Nov']})
```

df3:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrHm9.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join, if only `X` is joined column `on` parameter can be omit:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')
print (df)
    A    B      X   C    D
0  NA   50  IW233  12  Jan
1  EU   23  IW455  50  Aug
2  LA   21  IW455  50  Aug
3  ME  100  IW100  16  Nov
```

If multiple same columns names:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='X', how='left')
print (df)
    A    B      X   C    D
0  NA   50  IW233  12  Jan
1  EU   23  IW455  50  Aug
2  LA   21  IW455  50  Aug
3  ME  100  IW100  16  Nov
```

Comment: Thanks! I am able to merge but all values from the right dataframe have now become null. Any suggestions as to why this might happen?

Comment: There can be problem different types, so need cast column `X` to same dtypes. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947365/2901002)

Comment: I changed both dtypes to string however the error is still there. All right values are still NaN

Comment: Maybe some whitespaces, then need `df1['X'] = df1['X'].astype(str).str.strip()`. Same for `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join` operator here:

```
>>> df1.join(df2.set_index('X'),on='X')
    A    B      X   C    D
0  NA   50  IW233  12  Jan
1  EU   23  IW455  50  Aug
2  LA   21  IW455  50  Aug
3  ME  100  IW100  16  Nov
```

So we first change the index of the right frame to `X` (since these are unique on the right frame, that is not a problem). Then we perform a join on the `X` column.