# Merge Two different dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas, I need to complete the following task, is there an effective way to do it?
There are 2 different dataframes, dfa and dfb:
[image: dfa]

[image: dfb]

I used this to merge them together:

```
df = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, left_on = ['a_retry','a_cca', 'a_rssif', 'a_lqif'], right_on = ['b_retry','b_cca', 'b_rssif', 'b_lqif'])
```

I got the df output:
[image: df]

However it is not my expectation.
The merged dataframe contains all columns, it is OK, but the rows shall not exceed the smaller one (aka. dfa), that means the row 3 must be dropped, the expected one is:
[image]
How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected, because duplicates per all 4 columns.

So need remove duplicates rows by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
dfa = dfa.drop_duplicates(subset=['a_retry','a_cca', 'a_rssif', 'a_lqif'])
dfb = dfb.drop_duplicates(subset=['b_retry','b_cca', 'b_rssif', 'b_lqif'])
```

But if need match duplicates rows, is it possible with new column by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), which is used for `merge`:

```
dfa['new'] = dfa.groupby(['a_retry','a_cca', 'a_rssif', 'a_lqif']).cumcount()
dfb['new'] = dfb.groupby(['b_retry','b_cca', 'b_rssif', 'b_lqif']).cumcount()

df = (pd.merge(dfa, 
               dfb, 
               left_on = ['a_retry','a_cca', 'a_rssif', 'a_lqif', 'new'], 
               right_on = ['b_retry','b_cca', 'b_rssif','b_lqif', 'new']).drop('new', axis=1))
```

Comment: seems it works with small dataset, when i verified the solution with bigger one, df returns empty, not know why...

Comment: You can check `print(dfa.dtypes)` and `print (dfb.dtypes)` - need same for match columns

Comment: @RuiHuang - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947365/2901002) for better explanation.

Comment: Thanks, got the following outputs: a_retry    int64
a_cca      int64
a_rssif    int64
a_lqif     int64
new        int64
dtype: object
b_retry    int64
b_cca      int64
b_rssif    int64
b_lqif     int64
new        int64
dtype: object, do I need to concern dtype: object?

Comment: @RuiHuang - all columns are `int64`, so it should working. Is possible add some row manually for matching? Because it seems big data not matched...

Comment: I converted both dfa and dfb to int64, and dfa: 72 rows × 4 columns, dfb: 73 rows × 4 columns, not so big... maybe something else wrong? What do you mean by adding some row?

Comment: I think problem should be no match if get empty dataframe. If dupes, new column `g` should help, it create indicator column for uniqness uf duplicayed rows.