# Merge dataframes Python without duplications

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` and I want to merge them.

Dataframe `df1` is as follows:

```
   IDs          Value1      Value2       
   AB              1          3
   AB              1          1
   AB              2          4           
   BC              2          2
   BC              5          0         
   BG              1          1         
   RF              2          2
```

and dataframe `df2` is as follows:

```
   IDs          Issue     
   AB              AA
   AB              AAA
   AB              BA
   BC              CC
   BC              CA    
   BG              A        
   RF              D
```

and the desired output is `df3`:

```
   IDs          Value1      Value2        Issue     
   AB              1          3             AA
   AB              1          1             AAA
   AB              2          4             BA
   BC              2          2             CC
   BC              5          0             CA
   BG              1          1             A
   RF              2          2             D
```

Currently, the following:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='IDs',right_on='IDs',how='inner')
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='IDs',right_on='IDs',how='left')
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='IDs',right_on='IDs',how='outer')
```

do not work, since they produce a result similar to the following:

```
   IDs          Value1      Value2        Issue     
   AB              1          3             AA
   AB              1          1             AA
   AB              2          4             AA
   BC              2          2             CC
   BC              5          0             CC
   BG              1          1             A
   RF              2          2             D
```

meaning that they duplicate the first value of the `Issue` field from `df2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter column in both `DataFrame`s and add this column to parameter `on` in `merge`:

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('IDs').cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('IDs').cumcount()

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['IDs', 'g']).drop('g', axis=1)
print (df3)
  IDs  Value1  Value2 Issue
0  AB       1       3    AA
1  AB       1       1   AAA
2  AB       2       4    BA
3  BC       2       2    CC
4  BC       5       0    CA
5  BG       1       1     A
6  RF       2       2     D
```

**Details**:

```
print (df1)
  IDs  Value1  Value2  g
0  AB       1       3  0
1  AB       1       1  1
2  AB       2       4  2
3  BC       2       2  0
4  BC       5       0  1
5  BG       1       1  0
6  RF       2       2  0

print (df2)
  IDs Issue  g
0  AB    AA  0
1  AB   AAA  1
2  AB    BA  2
3  BC    CC  0
4  BC    CA  1
5  BG     A  0
6  RF     D  0
```

Comment: This solution does not seem to work. I keep getting exactly the same issue described in my question above.

Comment: @user37143 - Really interesting, for me it working very nice.

Comment: @user37143 - Added output of columns `g` - for duplicated values is incrementing integers - can you check it?

Comment: @jezrael yes that's my output as well, but the join still messes things up, returning the first occurence of "Issue" duplicated

Comment: @user37143 - There is also `g` in parameter `on` ? Like `pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['IDs', 'g'])` ?

Comment: @jezrael Yes and I have also tried: `pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on=['IDs','g'],right_on=['IDs','g']).drop('g',axis=1)`

Comment: problem is with `how='outer'`, it seems `how='left'` should working nice

Comment: @jezrael In any case, I think your answer is the correct one, I just have to double check everything again, thanx for the help.

Comment: @user37143 - It should working, maybe possible problem some whitespaces in `ids` column or not [same types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947365/2901002). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.concat` to literally join by the index of the dataframe.  This means both of your dataframes have to be preordered and you simply "pasting" one dataframe next to the other.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2[['Issue']], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  IDs  Value1  Value2 Issue
0  AB       1       3    AA
1  AB       1       1   AAA
2  AB       2       4    BA
3  BC       2       2    CC
4  BC       5       0    CA
5  BG       1       1     A
6  RF       2       2     D
```