# merging two data frames but getting an empty data frame in Pandas

Tags: pandas

```
fico_score1=pd.merge(fico_score,file_handler, on='customerInputSocialsecuritynumber')
```

customerInputSocialsecuritynumber is available in both the data frames.

Comment: Can you add some data samples? Maybe problem with [types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947365/2901002)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the left join parameter:

```
fico_score1=pd.merge(fico_score,file_handler, on='customerInputSocialsecuritynumber', how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. The customerInputSocialsecuritynumber of file_handler was int and customerInputSocialsecuritynumber of fico_score was a string. That is why it was not able to join the data Frames.
I converted the str column to int and then merged it.

fico_score["customerInputSocialsecuritynumber"]=fico_score["customerInputSocialsecuritynumber"].astype(int)      fico_score1=pd.merge(fico_score,file_handler,on='customerInputSocialsecuritynumber')