# Is there a way to sum all the values in a row in excel with the same key value using Pandas Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to compare two Excel and sum all the actual values that have the same key value.

```
example sheet.

sheet 1                  | sheet 2

index  id  count         | index    id   name

  1    a     12          |   1       a     qg1

  2    b     15          |   2       c     ff2

  3    c     21          |   3       f     dv1

  4    b      5          |   4       b     bm5
       .                             .
       .                             .
```

In above case, I refer to sheet2 and sum the actual value(count) of the values with the same ID in sheet1.(id a | 100, id b |20 ...)

The code below takes too long because each ID is indexed.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


pcode_quantity = pd.read_csv('/1.csv',delimiter=',')

product_info = pd.read_csv('/2.csv' , delimiter=',')

product_list = product_info.id.tolist()

purchase_id = pcode_quantity.id.tolist()

purchase_count = pcode_quantity['count'].tolist()

product_sum = 0

i =0

i2 = 0

product_lenth =len(product_list)

purchase_lenth = len(purchase_id)

dict_pcode = {}

while product_lenth > i:

    while purchase_lenth > i2:
        if product_list[i] == purchase_id[i2]:
            product_sum = product_sum + purchase_count[i2]
        i2=i2+1
    dict_pcode[product_list[i]]=product_sum
    product_sum = 0        
    i2= 0
    i= i+1

sum_pcode = pd.DataFrame(list(dict_pcode.items()))

sum_pcode.to_csv('/output.csv')
```

Is there any code that can speed up the above operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate `sum` by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) `product_info`, repalce possible missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and last for dictionary use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with converting to integers by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
pcode_quantity = pcode_quantity.groupby('id')['count'].sum()
df = product_info.join(pcode_quantity, on='id').fillna({'count': 0})
print (df)
      id name  count
index               
1      a  qg1   12.0
2      c  ff2   21.0
3      f  dv1    0.0
4      b  bm5   20.0

dict_pcode = df.set_index('id')['count'].astype(int).to_dict()
print (dict_pcode)
{'a': 12, 'c': 21, 'f': 0, 'b': 20}
```

Comment: The code and links you gave me really helped me a lot.Thank you very much

Comment: can i ask more question about your link?

Comment: @송준석 - sure, come on.

Comment: when i try to more join data frame in above situation, this error has occur.'ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat'

Comment: These are the columns of the data frame that I want to newly join. 'id','a_count','re' also new data frame(other) has lower data than df

Comment: @송준석 - need `astype` for convert columns to same types, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947365/2901002)

Comment: @송준석 - Thank you ;)